# Сделать выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, css

Нужна помощь, есть список, как из него сделать выпадающий? Но чтобы при выпадании пункта, там был сплошной текст, ну т.е раскрывающаяся информация.

```css
.rounded {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.rounded a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #DAD2CA;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded a:hover {
  background: #E9E4E0;
}

.rounded a:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #8FD4C1;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded">
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".rounded > li").on('click', function(){
  let div = $(this).find("div");
  if(div.css("display") == "none") div.slideDown();
  else div.slideUp();
});
```

```css
.rounded {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.rounded a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #DAD2CA;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}
.rounded li div {
  display: none;
}

.rounded a:hover {
  background: #E9E4E0;
}

.rounded a:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #8FD4C1;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="rounded">
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a>
    <div>Диктатура в России продлится 30 лет и закончится неудачной войной, а затем начнется новая эпоха перемен. В истории России чередуются времена революционных реформ и более длительные периоды авторитарной реакции. Начнем отсчет с первой неудачной попытки революции – восстания декабристов 1825 года. После него были 30 лет консервативного правления Николая І, закончившиеся поражением России в Крымской войне и смертью императора. Потом начались реформы (1857-1874) Александра ІІ. Затем царь пытался несколько "подморозить Россию". Эту политику ужесточил его сын Александр ІІІ и пытался вести Николай ІІ. Всего она продолжалась тоже около 30 лет (1875-1905). Провалился консервативный тренд после поражений в русско-японской войне 1904-1905 годов.</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a>
    <div>После жесточайших сталинских заморозков наступила короткая маленковско-хрущевская оттепель (1953-1964). А затем новый консервативный брежневско-андроповско-черненковский застой (1964-1985), на последнем этапе которого началась неудачная Афганская война. Потом пришла пора очередных революционных преобразований: горбачевской Перестройки и ельцинских реформ (1985-2000), закончившаяся новой реакционной диктатурой в России (2000 - ?).</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a>
    <div>Таким образом периоды консервативной реакции длились в истории России обычно около 30 лет (только брежневский был несколько короче). Заканчивались они почти всегда неудачной войной (исключение - сталинское правление). После этого следовал период реформ и революционных перемен (около 10-15 лет). Дальше к власти приходил новый реакционный диктатор (за исключением Александра ІІ, который сам из реформатора превратился в консервативного правителя) и все шло по кругу.</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a>
    <div>Исходя из этого исторического опыта, можно сделать прогноз на будущее России.</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Элемент списка</a>
    <div>Консервативная диктатура в России (или его преемника, если он неожиданно помрет) может продолжаться еще от нескольких до 10 лет (до 30 лет с момента прихода к власти). Закончится она неудачной войной. А затем начнется новая эпоха перемен.</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример аналогичного элемента:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)